# Not showing '/' at the end of folder name Django

Tags: python, django, bash, directory, slash

The django project I was working on involves uploading a tar of a folder and analyzing it's contents. When I have asked it to print the contents of that tar file, it is not printing '`/`' at the end of folder names.

Look at the code in `forms.py` corresponding to that class. (The uploaded tar contains assignment, so the class is named as `AssignmentImportForm`):

```
class AssignmentImportForm(forms.Form):
assignment_archive = forms.FileField(
                required=True,
                label="Assignment Archive",
                help_text="Please upload the assignment archive that follows the structure given in the above sample archive. Accepted archives are tar, tar.gz."
            )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['error_class']=DivErrorList
    super(AssignmentImportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def check_bulk_add(self, data):
    """
    Checks whether the uploaded folder for bulk files of assignment is in specified format

    Args:
        data: the archive corresponding to the folder to be uploaded

    Returns: true or false depending on whether the uploaded folder is in specified format

    """

    #<-----------------------------------------------------
    with Archive(fileobj=data['assignment_archive']) as archive111:
        x = archive111.getall_members()
        print(x)  ###########################################
       #HERE, I'VE ASKED TO PRINT ALL FILES AND FOLDERS INSIDE UPLOADED TAR
    #<-----------------------------------------------------

    if 'assignment_archive' in self.changed_data and data.get('assignment_archive', ''):
        err_message = bulk_import_check(data, self.this_course)
        if err_message != '':
            raise forms.ValidationError(err_message)

    else:
        if not hasattr(self, 'assignment_archive'):
            return
```

I've asked it to print the contents of the tar file I've uploaded.
The contents of the tar file are like this:

```
- assignment.tar.gz
       |
       +---Addition
             |
             +---Configuration
                   |
                   \----Configuration.txt
```

But it is not printing '`/`' at end of foldernames. But for one tar file, it is printing '`/`'. For remaining tar files, it printing like this:[image]

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Why should it print a slash? The slash is *not* part of the directory, it is a separator.

Comment: For one tar file,it is printing. But for remaining files, it is not printing.
Yes, slash is not part of directory but also you can't put '/' in name of directory. It should print '/' at the end of folder names.

Comment: yes, but I think that is more due to the tar program that creates the tarball. The names are written in the tarball, and so the program can decide what how to do that.